# How to tell if a Word selection is revised in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, revision

I am writing a VBA procedure in Word 2010 that searches a document for a search term. If it is found, I want to run some other code, but only if no portion of the resultant text is revised. So I can't just loop through the document revisions, because I need to find text that is not revised. I would like to either exclude revised text from the search (but I couldn't find an option under Selection.Find that did that), or check if the selected text is revised after the search executes (but I couldn't find an option under Selection.Range.Revisions that did that either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, based on quick try and test I've just made, that the answer is quite simple.
You need to find appropriate text range and check `.Revisions property` as follows (here, for `Selection`):

```
If Selection.Range.Revisions.Count > 0 Then
     'selected range is inside revision
Else 
     'selected range is not revised
End if
```

Comment: Wow. Definitely been staring at the screen for too long. Thanks for the answer. Yes, that is simple!